# Spaces not registered when using onChange on <input>

Tags: html, reactjs

Upon pressing of space onChange event is not getting called on my html input element.

Here's what I tried.

```
class FilterDropDown extends React.PureComponent {
state = {
      query: '',
    };

handleKeyPress = (evt) => {
      this.setState({ query: evt.target.value });
    };

render() {
      const { placeholder, items, id } = this.props;
      return (
        <DropDown
          placeholder={placeholder}
          open={this.state.show}
          onToggle={this.disableAppScrollAndToggleShowState}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          value={this.props[id]}
        >
          {
            this.props.filterable
            && (
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-undef
            <DropDown.Item disabled className="filters__option-text-filter">
              <div className="wrapper">
                <Label className="filter-dropdown__search-icon" />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={this.handleKeyPress}
                  size="sm"
                  placeholder={this.props.filterPlaceholder}
                  aria-label="filter-dropdown"
                  value={this.state.query}
                />
                <Button className="filter-dropdown__clear" onClick={this.resetQuery} />
              </div>
            </DropDown.Item>
            )
          }

          {
            items
              .filter(item => item.value.length > 0
                && item.value.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.query.toLowerCase()))
              .map(item => (
                <DropDown.Item
                  active={item.value === this.props[id]}
                  key={item.value}
                  eventKey={item.value}
                >
                  <span className="filter-options">{`${item.value} (${item.count})`}</span>
                </DropDown.Item>
              ))
          }
        </DropDown>
      );
    }
}
```

I am not posting the whole code but just enough to understand the use.
Also this input field is within the `React Bootstraps Dropdown` element, which is not allowing the input to accept spaces.

Heres a link of the documentation of react Dropdown `https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/`. If we look at the `Custom Dropdown Components` example the input box implemented there also doesn't allow spaces.

Is there a way I can deal with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The code even is fine, is not optimal (specially for learning porpuses).

What it might what you are looking for is to visualize the value in the imput at the time the user is typing:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        query: '',
    }

    handleKeyPress = (evt) => {
        this.setState({ query: evt.target.value }, () => {
            console.log("query: " + this.state.query) // this is for debugging
        });
    };

    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text"
                onChange={this.handleKeyPress}
                size="sm"
                placeholder={this.props.filterPlaceholder}
                aria-label="filter-dropdown"
                value={this.state.query}
                />
                <h1>query: {this.state.query}</h1>
                {/* this is for visualing the changes in the component*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have updated my example and I am not adding a few functions as it would make the code look confusing and posting only the details enough to understand my situation here. I hope my example is more elaborate now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass `e` in the parameter of `handleKeyPress` function.

`onChange={e => this.handleKeyPress(e)}`

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={e => this.handleKeyPress(e)}
  size="sm"
  placeholder={this.props.filterPlaceholder}
  aria-label="filter-dropdown"
  value={this.state.query}
/>
```